# Implement PHP Web Push (without Composer)

Tags: php, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im trying to setup browser push notifications for my website.
But im failing to implement the serverside code which sends the push notification.
(I know there is the web-push-php library but i cant use composer because an other framework is incompatible with it)

I try to build a php utility class which sends a api call to googles fcm service (or whatever service clientside logic returns as subscription endpoint)

---

So I began testing with postman, but all i get is just a authentication error.
I think i dont understand the api structure.

**My Token / Key collection:**

VAPID Keys:

```
{
  "subject": "mailto:mymail@mail.ch",
  "publicKey": "Token_A",
  "privateKey": "Token_B"
}
```

Subscription Browser Result:

```
{
    "endpoint": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/Token_C",
    "keys": {
        "auth": "Token_D",
        "p256dh": "Token_E"
    }
}
```

**Here is what i configured in postman:**

URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/Token_C

Headers:

-> Authorization: key=Token_D

-> Content: application/json

Body:

```
{
 "to" : "Token_A",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 },
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title"
 }
}
```

---

Is there any PHP library that handles this for me?

Or is there any (usable) documentation of how the api call has to be structured?

-- note:

Everything i did was according to the following documentation from google
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user

Comment: Try using  `Authorization` instead of `Authentication`

Comment: My fault ^^', I used Authorization Header not Authentication.
- i fixed it in the article